# algorithms math - how do I solve and substitute?

Tags: algorithm, math

I can't understand the basic math behind algorithms. For example, here's a question:

If

> f(n) = O(g(n))

is

> f(n) * log(f(n)^c) = O(g(n) * log(g(n)))

?

How do I go about answering this question? From what I understand so far, f(n) = O(g(n)) only when g(n) <= c(g(n)) and c and n are non-negative. So I need to start plugging values into the above based on that, but how do I do that? Say if I chose c=5 and n=2, would I plug the values like so: f(2) * log(f(2)^5) = 5(g(2) * log(g(2))) Would that mean that the answer to the original question is false?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

`f(n) * log(f(n)^c) = c * f(n) * log(f(n)) = O(1) * O(g(n)) * log(O(g(n))) = O(1) * O(g(n)) * O(log(g(n))) = O(g(n) * log(g(n))`.

So the answer to the question is true. All what you need here is properties of logarithm function.

There is one step that can be not clear here: why is `log(O(g(n))) = O(log(g(n)))`?
Proof: if `f(n) = O(g(n))`, there is a constant `C` such that for sufficiently large `n`
`f(n) <= C * g(n)`. Thus, `log(f(n)) <= log(C * g(n)) = log(g(n)) + log(C)`. We can use `C2 = 2` and obtain `log(f(n)) <= C2 * log(g(n))` for sufficiently large `n`.

Comment: I'm confused, how did you get this: log(C * g(n)) = log(g(n)) + C  ? Shouldn't it read like this instead: log(C) + log(g(n)) ?

Comment: Can you explain C2 portion? I'm not quite getting it. 1) What is C2, and why did you make it equal to 2? 2) How does this work: log(f(n)) <= C2 * log(g(n)) ? I thought that it was supposed to translate to log(C2 * g(n)).

Comment: @haosmark C2 is just another constant. For sufficiently large n, log(C) < log(g(n)). Thus 2 * log(g(n)) > log(C) + log(g(n)) >= log(f(n)).

Comment: do you know a book or a resource with similar problems and solutions to them (with explanations)? I very shaky in this subject

Answer (score 0):

By f(n) = O(g(n)) , you mean

there exists a k such that f(n) <= k.g(n) for some n >= N_1. -----1

which implies log(f(n)^c) <= log(k^c) + log(g(n)^c) <= K*log(g(n)^c) for n >= N_2 and for K= max{log(k^c),2} -----2

which gives us the the required answer by multiplication of 1& 2

f(n) * log(f(n)^c) = O(g(n) * log(g(n))).

Answer (score 0):

You're given `f(n) = O(g(n))` which means that beyond some point `f(n)` is at most a fixed positive multiple of `g(n)`. You don't know where that point is, and you don't know the positive multiple. Still you know that

```
(⋆)    f(n) ≤ k * g(n) for n > n₀ for some k > 0
```

even though `k` and `n₀` are unknown. (I used `k` to avoid a name collision with `c` in the second part of the problem.)

Now you're asked to show that `f(n) * log(f(n)^c) = O(g(n) * log(g(n)))`.

Logarithms turn multiplication into addition: `log(x * y) = log(x) + log(y)`. That said, unsurprisingly, they turn repeated multiplication (which is exponentiation) into repeated addition (which is multiplication): `log(x^y)= y * log(x)`.

First notice that `log(f(n)^c) = c log(f(n))` because `log(x^y) = y * log(x)`. So you may rewrite the problem: show `c * f(n) * log(f(n)) = O(g(n) * log(g(n)))`.

What's more you can abandon the `c` on the left hand side: if something is at most a constant times something else (big-O), then any multiple of it is at most some other constant multiplied by the something else. Again you can rewrite the problem: show `f(n) * log(f(n)) = O(g(n) * log(g(n)))`.

Now take the logarithm of (⋆):

```
(⋆)    f(n) ≤ k * g(n) for n > n₀ for some k > 0
(⋆⋆)   log(f(n)) ≤ log(k) + log(g(n)) for n > n₀ for some k > 0
```

The second only follows because log is an increasing function, so if numbers increase their logarithms increase --- taking the logarithm preserves order.

Now you need to multiply these two together to get something like the answer. Again this multiplication preserves order. If `a ≤ A` and `b ≤ B` then `ab ≤ AB`.

```
(⋆⋆⋆)  f(n) * log(f(n)) ≤ k * g(n) * log(g(n)) + k * log(k) * g(n) 
                  --- for n > n₀ for some k > 0
```

Now the left hand side is as in the problem, so you need to show the right hand side is at most some multiple of `g(n) * log(g(n))` to finish up.

The first term on the right is exactly the sort of thing you need, but the second term is not a multiple of `g(n) * log(g(n))`, yet it increases the right hand side if `log(k)>0`, so you can't just throw it away: doing that would decrease the right hand side, and the left hand side might no longer be at most the right hand side.

(Of course if `log(k)≤0` you can just throw the second term  away which increases the right hand side and you're done: there's a multiple of `g(n) * log(g(n))` there which is what you want.)

Instead what you need to do is increase `k * log(k) * g(n)` into another multiple of `g(n) * log(g(n))`. Increasing it means the left hand side is still at most the right hand side, and this makes the whole of the right hand side be a multiple of `g(n) * log(g(n))` and the proof will be complete.

To do this, you need to multiply `k * log(k) * g(n)` by `log(g(n))`. Provided `log(g(n)) ≥ 1` (again beyond some point), which seems reasonable in the theory of algorithms, this will make `k * log(k) * g(n)` bigger. (I could fuss here, but I won't!) So you may say that

```
(⋆⋆⋆)  f(n) * log(f(n)) ≤ k * g(n) * log(g(n)) + k * log(k) * g(n) 
                  --- for n > n₀ for some k > 0
```

But `log(g(n)) ≥ 1` for `n > n₁` and so multiplying the second term by `log(g(n))` does not decrease it, so

```
   f(n) * log(f(n)) ≤ k * g(n) * log(g(n)) + k * log(k) * g(n) * log(g(n))
                  --- for n > max(n₀,n₁) for some k > 0
```

and simplifying the right hand side

```
   f(n) * log(f(n)) ≤ k(1+log(k)) * g(n) * log(g(n))
                  --- for n > max(n₀,n₁) for some k > 0
```

just gives a multiple of `g(n) * log(g(n))` because k is a constant. i.e. take `c = k(1+log(k))` to be the positive constant you need. (Earlier you eliminated the case where `log(k) ≤ 0`.) So

```
   f(n) * log(f(n)) = O(g(n) * log(g(n)))
```